# In Azure Eventhub how to send incoming data to a sql database

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I have some data being collected that is in an xml format. Something that looks like

```
<OLDI_MODULE xmlns="">
 <StStoHMI_IBE>
<PRack>0</PRack>
<PRackSlotNo>0</PRackSlotNo>
<RChNo>0</RChNo>
<RChSlotNo>0</RChSlotNo>
```

This data is sent to Azure Eventhub. I wanted to send this data to a SQL database. I created a stream in Azure Stream Analytics that takes this input and puts it in a SQL database. But when the input format is asked for the input stream, there are only JSON,CVS and Avro. Which of these formats can I use? Or which of the azure services should I use to move data from Eventhub to sql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest option is to use Azure Stream Analytics as you intended to do. But yes, you will have to convert the xml to json or another supported format before you can use the data.

The other options is more complex, requires some code and a way to host the code (using a worker role or web job for instance) but gives the most flexibility. That option is to use an `EventProcessor` to read the data from the Event Hub and put it in a database.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted/ for how to set this up.

The main work is done in the `Task IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable messages)` method. Based on the example it will be something like:

```
async Task IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
{
    foreach (EventData eventData in messages)
    {
        string xmlData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());

        // Parse the xml and store the data in db using Ado.Net or whatever you're comfortable with
    }

    //Call checkpoint every 5 minutes, so that worker can resume processing from 5 minutes back if it restarts.
    if (this.checkpointStopWatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    {
        await context.CheckpointAsync();
        this.checkpointStopWatch.Restart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON would be a good data format to be used in Azure Event Hub. Once you receive the data in Azure Event Hub. You can use Azure Stream Analytics to move the data SQL DB.

Azure Stream Analytics consists of 3 parts : input, query and output. Where input is the event hub , output is the SQL DB. The query should be written by you to select the desired fields and output it.

Check out the below article:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-define-outputs/

Stream Analytics would be Azure resource you should look into for moving the data from Event Hub

Comment: My databses is on a VM in the cloud. Azure Stream analytics only moves it to an azure SQLdb and not if it is in a VM in the cloud.